# How can i do Time formatting in XSL

Tags: sql, xml, xslt

I would like to formatting numbers to HH:mm in XLS. The main problem is that, the input number is like 810 (-> 8:10) and 1530 (-> 15:30)
How can i do it?

I tried to use this:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string-length(IND)=4">
        <!--<td><xsl:value-of select="IND"></xsl:value-of></td>-->
        <td><xsl:value-of select="format-time(IND, 'HH:mm')"/></td>
    </xsl:when>   ...
```

But it is drop an error:
XML-22018: (Error) Parse Error in format-time function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
<xsl:variable name="hrLen" select="string-length(IND) - 2" />
<td><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(IND, 1, $hrLen),
                                 ':',
                                 substring(IND, $hrLen + 1))" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(format-number(IND div 100,'00.00'), '.', ':')"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if using Microsoft's XSL engine:

```
<xsl:template match="Time">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(text(),'00:00')"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Or this for other XSL engines including MS (recommended):

```
<xsl:template name="FormatTime">
  <xsl:param name="numericTime" select="0" />
  <xsl:variable name="fourDigitString" select="format-number($numericTime,'0000')"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($fourDigitString,1,2),':',substring($fourDigitString,3,2))"/>
</xsl:template>
```

**Full Example:**

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Time">
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:element name="Universal">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:call-template name="FormatTime">
          <xsl:with-param name="numericTime" select="text()" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:element name="MicrosoftAndMaybeOthers">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(text(),'00:00')"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>

  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="FormatTime">
    <xsl:param name="numericTime" select="0" />
    <xsl:variable name="fourDigitString" select="format-number($numericTime,'0000')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($fourDigitString,1,2),':',substring($fourDigitString,3,2))"/>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Root>
  <Time>810</Time>
  <Time>1538</Time>
</Root>
```

More info on the function: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_formatnumber.asp

Comment: I don't think this is going to work unless you (1) divide the number by 100 first, and (2) define a custom decimal format where `:` is the decimal separator. Or ... (see my answer)

Comment: Agreed - I'd tested in Visual Studio and it worked, but on XSLFiddle it gave the wrong results.  I've now provided a universal solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling format-time(). This is an XSLT 2.0 function. Are you using an XSLT 2.0 processor? - you don't say, and oddly, no-one has asked.

If you are using XSLT 2.0, then you can call this function as

```
format-time($time, '[H01]:[m01]')
```

However, first you have to construct $time as an xs:time value. Starting with the number 810, you have to do `xs:time('00:00:00') + ((($n idiv 100) * 60) + ($n mod 100))*xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1M')` - which is a bit much work just to insert a colon.

So I think my preferred 2.0 solution would probably be

```
replace(string($N), '(\d\d)$', ':$1')
```